# VTUNE: Cannot display data

Tags: ubuntu, profiling, debian, intel-vtune

I'm using Intel Vtune to do some analyzis: memory access, access contention, etc. and I'm getting this error: Cannot display data. The data cannot be displayed: there is no viewport applicable for the data.

I'm using Debian 6, Intel Vtune Amplifier (GUI) Update 5 (2013).

I've found some suggestion for this problem on Ubuntu but didn't find anything for debian and the suggested solutions for ubuntu seems no applicable for debian.

Answer (score -1):

First of all do sanity check that hardware event based collection actually works on your system, run:

> amplxe-cl -collect lightweight-hotspots -d 20

This is simple 20 seconds system-wide collection,You should see a summary report as result.
 If it doesn't pass please let know what error do you see?

If it passes then try to run your application under the same analysis and make sure it runs without errors or unexpected exits:

> amplxe-cl -collect lightweight-hotspots -- your_app

If the latter also passes then the main reason of not receiving data in memory access and other in-depth event based analysis could be that your workload is too short and did not collect enough samples. Try increase the analysis duration to at least 3-5 minutes.
 Try using General Exploration analysis - it reports the most common CPU performance metrics.

And I would also recommend upgrading to Update 8 of VTune Amplifier XE